# How can I persist the modified V4L2 (Guvcview) profile of a webcam?

Tags: camera, settings, persistence, v4l

I have a USB web camera that gives suboptimal results when I plug it in (Linux seems to apply its own V4L2 settings to it that it thinks are best, they are not). Mainly, it operates at a low FPS. But if I open Guvcview, select "Settings" -> "Hardware defaults" in the menu, and add some minor modifications, I can get a higher FPS and overall better quality.

If I close Guvcview and open it again, the settings are reset in Guvcview, but the changes I made stay active in other apps like video chat software. However, if I unplug the webcam, the changes are lost everywhere, and after plugging in again I have a worse quality again.

What I do for now is I saved the changes in Guvcview as a .gpfl file (menu -> "Settings" -> "Save profile"), and whenever I reconnect the webcam, I open Guvcview and load the profile with "Load profile".

How can I make these settings persist so that I never have to do this again, and have them applied to only this specific video device and not others?

Comment: I have no knowledge at all of guvcview, but if you can figure out how to load this settings file from command line, the right way to go about this would be to execute exactly that command from a udev rule that triggers when your camera gets connected.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. All cameras go back to default settings after losing power. (I.e. replugging, reboot PC, etc) this is the nature of the hardware.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this❗ (if you haven't already...) I've tested this on Debian 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 with a Logitech C920. I use it every day on a Debian system. In general, I refuse to believe that a thing "can't" be done in Linux.

## SUMMARY

1. Find out the name of your Linux Device
2. Create a script to be run at login
3. Point to the script from Linux Autostart

## DETAILS

### Find out the name of your Linux Device

In the terminal:
If you don't have it, install **v4l-utils**. Then run the following command:

`v4l2-ctl --list-devices`

You will see output similar to the following:

```
HD Pro Webcam C920 (usb-0000:00:14.0-10.3):
    /dev/video2
    /dev/video3
    /dev/media1

USB Video: USB Video (usb-0000:00:14.0-10.4):
    /dev/video4
    /dev/video5
    /dev/media2
```

In my case, the webcam (Logitech C920) uses `/dev/video2` so I'll specify that in the upcoming script.

### Create a bash script to be run at login

> There are several ways to do this. Here are two:

With `sudo` permissions, place a script in `/usr/local/bin`. I named mine `c920.sh`

**Option 1: Using guvcview**

Example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

sleep 10
guvcview -d /dev/video2 --profile=<profile_name>.gpfl &
sleep 1
pkill -f "guvcview"
```

> Change the profile name to whatever you have saved your profile as and include the path.

The script runs guvcview and specifies the device you want with the correct profile. I added some sleep time in there in case you have a lot of things starting up when you log in. Adjust as you see fit.
Then, the script kills the guvcview process. That's it.

> `man guvcview` has lots of goodies.

**Option 2: Using v4l-utils**

```bash
#!/bin/bash
sleep 10
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c brightness=125
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c contrast=126
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c saturation=115
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c white_balance_temperature_auto=0
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c gain=175
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c power_line_frequency=2
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c white_balance_temperature=4515
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c sharpness=128
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c backlight_compensation=0
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c exposure_auto=1
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c exposure_absolute=250
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c exposure_auto_priority=0
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c focus_auto=0
```

> Note: This program has a newer version as of 1/2024 with different control names. See the end of this post for new config.

> Note: I give this second option because **guvcview** can conflict with other programs and give varying results. Try to only use one webcam configuration program at a time.
> That said, if you do encounter a conflict (settings suddenly change values, such as the gain) then you could find the settings you like best with **guvcview**, then uninstall that program, and configure your settings with **v4l-utils** as shown above.
> vl4 is actually what I use, and these settings work in my lab (dark background), but you might need to tweak them! Also, they don't take into account resolution and FPS. But if you set these with another program, they should remain in Linux's "memory".

Set the script to executable: `chmod +x c920.sh`

### Point to the script from Linux Autostart

There are a variety of ways to do this. I'm using a Desktop Entry here:
Go to `/etc/xdg/autostart` and create a .desktop file. I chose `c920.desktop` as the name.

Add the following:

```bash
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/local/bin/c920.sh
```

### Try logging out and rebooting. Make sure it works

> This solution is just one possibility. In Linux, there are several!

> Beware, you might encounter flaky issues if you have multiple video devices and multiple paths. Be ready to troubleshoot! Usually it means that two webcam config programs are conflicting.
> A person might also consider looking into udev rules, or a Unit file in Linux with service. See the link below for more.
> Someone had mentioned placing the script (command) in .bashrc but this is problematic because it will run every time a bash shell/terminal is opened unless you incorporate it into a for loop.
> Also, some people have better luck with the C922 and/or the Brio (especially on Ubuntu).

[This link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/webcam_setup) has great information on using `v4l-utils` and webcam setup in Linux in general.

> Final Note: In an ideal world, companies such as Logitech, Razer, Rode, and others would embrace the Linux community. I don't think a simple GUI interface and driver is too much to ask. I'll settle for a .deb version to start!  Hint hint... Good article about this problem: [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/904776/)

---

#### New config for v4l2-ctl

```bash
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c brightness=125
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c contrast=126
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c saturation=115
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c white_balance_automatic=0
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c gain=175
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c power_line_frequency=2
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c white_balance_temperature=4515
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c sharpness=128
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c backlight_compensation=0
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c auto_exposure=1
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c exposure_time_absolute=250
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c exposure_dynamic_framerate=0
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c focus_automatic_continuous=0
```